# Image View not showing image in a Custom ListView

Tags: android, listview, navigation-drawer

There are no errors that are crashing the program, I just want the image to be aligned. The Image is shown to the left of the Text if the ImageView is placed before the TextView

My Custom Layout for NavigationDrawer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/bookName" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/bookImageView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How to make the image float right of the text and about some points from the right edge of the listview.
One more thing, my layout is being used in a NavigationDrawer, so the ListView covers less than the full width...
Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of what you are seeing? or what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Change `layout_width` of `TextView` from `match_parent` to `wrap_content`:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

Comment: you mean "wrap_content"..yea the images does show, but i want the image to be at the edge of the drawer...at some specified points from the right edge

Comment: Then use layout_marginRight for ImageView in place of marginLeft